# Clock In & Out System on Google Form

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I created a Google App Script that creates a form to allow users to choose their name from the dropdown list and it will direct them to the next page. On the next page, with their name and a little hint saying they need to clock out (see the image), as well as their options to choose whether they want to clock in or out.

After I run this script, I created a form with all those options on it. But the question is how to set a description that has the says last time they clock in is "mm/DD/yyyy" + you need to clock OUT" and vise versa.

How would I do this through Google script?

Here is the script:

```
function setUpForm() {
  //Set up form
  var form = FormApp.create('Clock In & Out System');
  form.setTitle('Clock In Form');

  //Set up first page
  var item1 = form.addListItem()
                  .setTitle('Employee Name')
                  .setRequired(true);
  var page2 = form.addPageBreakItem()
                  .setTitle('Fred');

  //Set up second page (Fred)
  var item2 = form.setTitle('Fred');
  var item2a = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
                  .setTitle('Clocking in or out?')
                  .setChoiceValues(["Clock in", "Clock out"])
                  .setRequired(true);
  //Change last time clock in/out message and update reminder on what to do next
  var page3 = form.addPageBreakItem()
                  .setTitle('Wilma')
                  .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);

  //Set up third page (Wilma)
  var item3 = form.setTitle('Wilma');
  var item3a = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
                   .setTitle('Clocking in or out?')
                   .setChoiceValues(["Clock In", "Clock Out"])
                   .setRequired(true);
  var page4 = form.addPageBreakItem()
                  .setTitle('Betty')
                  .setGoToPage(FormApp.PageNavigationType.SUBMIT);

  //Setup forth page (Betty)
  var item4 = form.setTitle('Betty')
  var item4a = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
                   .setTitle('Clocking in or out?')
                   .setChoiceValues(["Clock In", "Clock Out"])
                   .setRequired(true);

  //Set up name choices on first page
  item1.setChoices([
   item1.createChoice("Fred", page2),
   item1.createChoice("Wilma", page3),
   item1.createChoice("Betty", page4)
  ]);
}
```

Here is the image:

[image: Picture in Google Form]

Comment: What form element do you pretend to use to display the "You need to clock in" message? Assuming that the clock in time is the timestamp of the submitted form, what should be displayed when there isn't a "clock IN" time for an employee?

Comment: I don't believe there are elements to display the "You need to clock in" message. All I did was I just added "You need to clock In" message as a Title

Comment: I think this is much simpler using a custom form in a sidebar/web app. You can then submit the form to a Google Form backend for storage, but would not be to constantly create new Google Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that we should have in mind is that all the changes to the form should be made before respondent open the form.

One way to add the last time that the responded checked in message is to run a function that adds that message to the form. Maybe the most convenient way for most cases is to use an onFormSubmit trigger that updates the form item that should hold the "last clocked in" message.

> NOTE: Script adopters should adapt it to their specific needs, but first they should understand what it does and how it does that.

For simplicity let say that we use a **Title** (Apps Script calls it **Section Header**) to hold the related message and that we have a form just with on Title and one Multiple Choice question and that the message should use a variables the clock in/out and the response timestamp. The following script will update the Title description on form submit, so the next time the user open the form to submit the clock in/out they will see the timestamp of the last time that they submitted a response. It should be added to a Script project bounded to the form.

```
/**
 * Update help text of first section header on form submit
 *
 * @param Object e Form submit event object
 * @param Object e.authMode A value from the ScriptApp.AuthMode enum.
 * @param Object e.response A FormResponse object, representing the user's response to the form as a whole.
 * @param Object e.source   A Form object, representing the Google Forms file to which the script is bound.
 * @param Object e.triggerUid   ID of trigger that produced this event.
 */
function updateHelpText(e) {
  // Get section headers.
  var formItems = e.source.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.SECTION_HEADER);

  // Get response timestamp
  var timestamp = e.response.getTimestamp();

  // Get script timezone
  var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();

  // Set timestamp format
  var format = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm';

  // Get the first section header. This form item will hold the message.
  var item = formItems[0];

  // Get clocked type
  var type = e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse();

  // Set message
  var message = Utilities.formatString('The last time you %s was %s',
                                       type,
                                       Utilities.formatDate(timestamp, timeZone, format));

  // Add message to section header
  item.setHelpText(message);

}

/**
 * Auxiliary function to validate on form submit function
 *
 */
function test(){

  // Create a form response
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var items = form.getItems();
  var x = items[1].getTitle();
  var formResponse = form.createResponse();
  formResponse
    .withItemResponse(
      items[1].asMultipleChoiceItem().createResponse('Clock in')
    );

  // Create on form submit event object
  var e = {}; // Form submit event object
  e.authMode    = ScriptApp.AuthMode.FULL; // A value from the ScriptApp.AuthMode enum.
  e.source = form;  // A Form object, representing the Google Forms file to which the script is bound.
  e.response = formResponse.submit(); // A FormResponse object, representing the user's response to the form as a whole.
  e.triggerUid  = '00000000'; // ID of trigger that produced this event.

  // Call the on form submit function
  updateHelpText(e);
}
```

Once the above code is added to the form script project, add a trigger following the instructions on [Installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

To adapt the above for the OP case, the adopters could add some logic to replace the 0 indexes by the corresponding indexes for the **Title** and the **Clock in or Clock out?** form items and item responses accordingly. Let say that `i` and `j` are used to hold the corresponding indexes, then beside adding the code to set that indexes on the following lines should be replaced the 0 indexes by `i` and `j` accordingly:

```
  // Get the first section header. This form item will hold the message.
  var item = formItems[i];

  // Get clocked type
  var type = e.response.getItemResponses()[j].getResponse();
```